# how to know whether a facebook user liked our "fan page" or not?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a website called masthee.in.In that website I have an account page(account.php) in which user can sign-up(create account) and sign-in.Now whenever user is trying to sign-up I want to track whether that person liked my facebook fan page or not.If not I want to show a popup like content locker to make that user like my facebook fan page.Can we achieve this using facebook's javascript sdk feature FB.getLoginStatus().If it is not possible to achieve this using FB.getLoginStatus() is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I'll be honest I don't know the answer as I have never done any facebook programming before. Could you possibly have a facebook like button on your page which likes your fan page. I assume you would be able to hook into the clicked event on this and then that would tell you whether they have liked it (Unless they need to log in I guess).

Answer (score 1):

Like gating is not allowed anymore, and you would need to get `user_likes` approved for that. Facebook will not approve it for like gating.

Comment: so what you are saying is there is no way to achieve this.

Comment: it is not allowed. so it does not really matter if there is a way.